# Can we say that a function is increasing/decreasing at a point where tangent is vertical?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I am analyzing this function: $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^3-x}$. The derivative is $f'(x)=\frac{3x^2-1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x^3-x)^2}}$. I found that $f'(x)>0$ when $x<-1 \text{ or } -1<x<-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$. Can I say that the function is increasing on interval $(-\infty, -\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})$ (include $x=-1$ even though the derivative does not exist at that point? I am thinking that the function continues to increase. It's been awhile since I did any analysis like this but I believe the definition of increasing function does not involve the derivative. Am I right?

Comment: The property of increasing or decreasing is much more elementary than anything involving calculus: is $f(x) < f(a)$ for all $x$ in some interval to the left of $a$, and is $f(a) < f(x)$ for all $x$ in some interval to the right of $a$?  If so, then $f$ is increasing at $x$.  A *sufficient condition* might be in terms of the derivative of $f$ at $a$ if it exists, but the failure of a derivative to exist should not make you think there is no way to conceive of what it means for a function to be increasing or decreasing somewhere.

Comment: As the last comment says, you don't need a derivative. However, you appear to have made errors in your use of the derivative. Try plotting a few values of $f(x)$ less than $-1/\sqrt3$ and see if you still believe it is decreasing there.

Comment: The comment above by @KCd is a full explanation. Note the same thing happens for the function $f(x)=x^{(1/3)}$ whose derivative fails to exist at $x=0$ yet $f(x)$ is increasing on the whole real line.

Comment: For instance, $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ is increasing on the whole real line, including at $x = 0$, where there is a vertical tangent. (After posting this comment I see that coffeemath said the same thing.) I made a typo in my previous comment: after the question I asked, the answer should have been "... $f$ is increasing at $a$".

Comment: @KCd Just noted my comment same as your last one... which I saw aftr typing it.

Comment: @DavidK: I definitely put the wrong sign, it's obvious from the graph. Thank you for correcting me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the disconnect here is that you're thinking about a specific point. Usually, when we talk about increasing/decreasing functions, or [monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) more generally, we're typically referring to an entire interval and looking at pairwise comparisons on that interval - not just at one point.

Further, the existence of the derivative is not a requisite condition for a function to be considered increasing.

One common definition of increasing is that a function $f$ is increasing on an interval $I$ if for any $x,y \in I$,  $y>x \Rightarrow f(y) \ge f(x)$, and $f$ is strictly increasing if $y>x \Rightarrow f(y) > f(x)$.

Note, this definition has nothing to do with derivatives, and the definition applies to a function over some interval - not just a single point!

The [floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) are (weakly) increasing over $\mathbb{R}$, but their derivatives are either $0$ or undefined for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

As KCd noted in their comment, we *can* use derivatives to arrive at a sufficient condition. If $f$ has a derivative that exists on an interval, and $f'(x) \ge 0$ everywhere on that interval, then we can show that $f$ is increasing between any two points on that interval based on the definition above, but the converse does not need to be true - a function can be increasing even if the derivative doesn't exist or is undefined.

Using the sufficient condition $f'(x) \ge 0$ makes it easy to think about monotonicity at a point because we typically evaluate derivatives at a point, but it really is a property of a function on an ordered set or an interval, not at a specific point.